# Does any one have an example of a website build in ZendFrameWork?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to know what this looks like.  I don't have any ideas about ZendFramework, and that makes me sad. :(

If any one knows of a site which is built in ZendFramework, or has any other experience with it, please do let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I would suggest adding more tags such as php zend-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for an up-to-date best-practice and feature-filled Zend Framework based application to be able to base things on myself, to little effect thus far.

I did come across a decent small version of that though last week - http://www.dodoapp.com/  It's a fairly simple ajax-enabled todo-list, with member self-registration, login and admin back-end, but no openId or major use of ACLs and so on that I'd love to have more live examples of.

http://www.dodoapp.com/ has at least been updated to use Zend_Application and the source code is downloadable.

Answer (score 4):

I believe zend does! Here http://framework.zend.com/about/casestudies

Also [magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is a notable application of the zend framework

**Update:**

Just found another post that you might find helpful. A more extensive list of zend framework based projects: http://devzone.zend.com/article/2060

Answer (score 1):

we've recently built a pretty large site with the Zend Framework, and there's not much good I can say about it. 
While it is a large repository of classes (some of them quite useful), there is little direction of how to put them together to build a large, durable system, and many of the "documented" ways are either outdated, not implemented yet, or flat-out too simple to be useful. When you bring this up to the developers, they often reacted dismissive and defended code that ultimately was thrown out much later.

Frameworks like Symfony or CodeIgniter, or even Cake save you the trouble of assembling all the classes to a working framework. They come "pre-assebled" and let you get to the business issues at hand right away, while still allowing you all the flexibility that the Zend framework clains to bring, but without all the pitfalls and frustration.

Do yourself a favor and consider these other frameworks. My personal favorite is Symfony.

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are several books on putting together systems using Zend Framework and with the newest version of the framework, it's easier than ever. I definitely think the Zend framework is one worth learning but I have looked at and used CakePHP. Zend framework is more useful if you want more control over how your project is set up and you are not after rapid out-out of the box stuff

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into Zend Framework for myself. It is really like a large Grey area without any help. I have been trying to find this help, only to be guided to Code Igniter. They have a few video tutorials that demonstrate use of the framework. Maybe this will give you a bit of an insight on Zend and how it works as well.

I feel to learn Zend requires some kind of instruction and maybe a mentor. This is why I gave up trying to learn it.

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Grey area without help? Try http://framework.zend.com/docs/quickstart :)

List of projects can be found on http://www.zfcounter.org/projects